# How to count the number of cells with a certain value in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google sheet with customers that came from different sources and bought different products. Table looks like this:

```
utm_campaign   user_product

campaign_1     1st_product
campaign_2     2nd_product
campaign_3     1st_product
campaign_1     2nd_product
campaign_2     1st_product
```

I want to count the number of cells in a row "user_product" with different values. what formula I should use to transform it in Data Studio into this:

```
utm_campaign   1st_product   2nd_product
campaign_1          1             1
campaign_2          1             1
campaign_3          1             0
```

I have tried this formula

```
SUM(
  CASE 
      WHEN user_product = "1st_product" 
      THEN "1" 
      ELSE "0"
  END
)
```

but something went wrong

*Field name contains invalid table alias: t0._339410717_*

Answer (score 1):

Seems right except you are casting the numbers as strings by using speech marks so it can't add them up

```
SUM(
  CASE 
      WHEN user_product = "1st_product" 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
  END
)
```

Alternatively you could put the two dimensions into a pivot table with a count to get your required answer